# Is the issue with openpyxl losing the existing graphs and charts resolved?

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

`Openpyxl` as of 2.5 did not save existing graphs and charts when a sheet was added to it or an existing sheet was updated with some new data. Has this issue been resolved? I have been running into the same problem with Python 2.7 and not been able to resolve it either.